# Read value within node in XML using PHP xpath

Tags: php, xpath

I have XML like below, and I want to read the value of `name` using PHP XPATH. I can read value if it is between start and end tags, but how to read value if XML is like this?

```
<a name="john" id="100" />
```

Comment: Please post your complete XML and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to get the value of name:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<a name="john" id="100" />');

$name = (string)$xml->xpath('/a/@name')[0];

echo $name; // Output: john
```

Comment: Thanks its working. Just one modification //a instead of /a in xpath

Comment: Good to hear it is working. Will you accept the answer?